# What are the figures of merit/ performance measurements I can use for deconvolution?

Tags: optics, microscopy

I'm currently performing deconvolution on a bunch of *2D* slices of [fluorescent beads](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biofiles/fluorescent-microparticles.html) using *MATLAB*. Now I want to measure the performance of different deconvolution methods on the filtering of the [PSF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function)(the Optical Transfer Function) of the slices. Can someone please tell me how this is possible/ suggest me papers that I can read up on to find out about these performance measurement tools for deconvolution

Thank you for your answers and please do not hesitate to ask me to clarify this subject any further.

Comment: How do you define "performance"?

Comment: You know the size of the beads you are imaging, so I would use that information to quantify the "performance" of the algorithm (@CuriousOne asks the right question, you have to define "performance"). What about to compare the size of the beads in the image with the real size? the winning method would be the one that gives a diameter closest to reality.

Comment: @fpdx what if we do not know the specific size of the beads? And you are going along the right lines, when you say 'winning method' of deconvolution.

Comment: @CuriousOne someone suggested a method where I could measure the intensity distribution of the bead in a particular plane. I want to understand more about this technique and the particular literature for it.

Comment: @fpdx please look at the comment where I tagged CuriousOne

Comment: Can you link to that suggestion? In general one has to be careful about deconvolution methods for problems that are not convolution problems, like microscopy. While it is tempting to assume that the light path in a microscope is a linear system, that's not the case. What we are usually measuring is the intensity distribution, but we lost the phase information, which makes it non-linear and naive deconvolution will give false results (like negative values for the reconstructed scattering function). That's why it is important to understand what your ultimate goal is.